# python: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects

Tags: python, mysql

I want to get pool number from employee table and use the pool number as parameter for query 1.i get error  python: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects.

```
import MySQLdb
import sys

factor_mm=sys.argv[1]
factor_yy=sys.argv[2]

con_pd1 = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'abc', '12345', 'test')

cursor_pd1=con_pd1.cursor()

query="select pool_number from employee where current_mm="+factor_mm+" and current_yy="+factor_yy+" ;"
cursor_pd1.execute(query)
pools=cursor_pd1.fetchall()
pool_list=[]
for pool in pools:
 pool_list.append(pool[0])

for pool in pool_list:
 pool_number=pool
 try:
    query1="select * from fnma_mbs where pool_number='"+pool_number+"' and current_mm="+factor_mm+" and current_yy="+factor_yy+" ;"
    cursor_pd1.execute(query1)
    cursor_seqdb1.execute(query1)

    numrows_pd1=cursor_pd1.rowcount
    numrows_seqdb1=cursor_seqdb1.rowcount
```

Comment: In modifying your code, have you fixed your problem? Or do you still get your error?

Comment: nope actually that was a mistake..still code give same error

Comment: If you don't know what "SQL injection" is or means, you should stop now and read about it.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `pools` after you execute query contain a list of tuples (each tuple consists of one element), for example something like `[('1'), ('2'), ('3')]`.

```
for pool in pools:
 pool_list.append(pools[0])
```

After execution of this code `pool_list`will contain `[('1'), ('1'), ('1')]`, because `pools[0] == ('1')`.
You should replace this code with

```
for pool in pools:
 pool_list.append(pool[0])
```

Comment: after that i got a error closing a closed connection in last

Comment: @Vivek Singh Add a full error text into your question. Or post it in comment

Comment: _mysql_exceptions.programmingerror  : closing a closed connection